# Img Click Event Listener Not Working On Custom Tab Of TXTextControl HTML5 Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, addeventlistener, txtextcontrol

I am using code provided in one of the TXTextControl blogs to create a custom tab for merge codes on their HTML5 editor. We are upgrading from version 16 to 22 and have our own custom merge codes in place, with a web service to pull in data, and, for obvious reasons want to keep this system in place. My custom tab has a dropdown for merge code groups which drives a second dropdown of merge codes within the selected group. Users add or delete merge codes by clicking on an img with either a plus or minus sign. Everything is in place - the dropdowns are working beautifully, but I cannot seem to bind the plus sign img to a click event. I've tried both jQuery and Javascript (commented out in the code snippet). I *am* making sure that the custom tab itself is loaded before attempting the bind, but to no avail. Absolutely nothing happens when I click the Plus.png image.  Anyone see the problem? Thanks in advance for any input!

Mike

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function loadDDLMergeCodeGroups() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#ddlMergeCodeGroup").load("MergeCodeGroups.txt");
            });
        }

        function loadDDLMergeCodes() {
            $("#ddlMergeCodeGroup").change(function() {
                $("#ddlMergeCode").load(encodeURI("textdata/" +    $(this).val() + ".txt"));
            });
        }

        function addInsertFieldEvent() {
            $("#insertField").bind('click', function() {
                alert('Hello!');    
            });
        }

        //function addInsertFieldEvent() {
        //    document.getElementById("insertField").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        //       alert('hello');
        //    });
        //}

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <cc1:TextControl ID="TextControl1" runat="server" Dock="Window" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // elements can be only added when the ribbon is completely loaded 
        TXTextControl.addEventListener("ribbonTabsLoaded", function (e) {
            addTab();
            loadDDLMergeCodeGroups();
            loadDDLMergeCodes();
            addInsertFieldEvent();
        });

        // this function adds a new tab and the tab content page 
        function addTab() {
            sCustomTab = "<li><a onclick='activateCustomTab();' id='tabCustom' data-applicationmodes='0' tabindex='-1' href='#!'>Merge Codes</a></li>";

            // add the new tab after the 'View' tab 
            document.getElementById('tabView').parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML(
                'afterend', sCustomTab);

            sCustomTabContent = "<div id='ribbonTabCustom' class='tab-content' style='display: none;'>";
            sCustomTabContent += "<div id='ribbonGroupCustom' class='ribbon-group'>";
            sCustomTabContent += "  <div class='ribbon-group-content'>";
            sCustomTabContent += "      <div class='ribbon-group-content-row'>";
            sCustomTabContent += "          <div class='ribbon-group-button-group'>";
            //sCustomTabContent += "              <div onclick='BtnCustomAction()' id='BtnCustom' class='ribbon-button ribbon-button-big' title='Custom'>";
            //sCustomTabContent += "                  <div class='ribbon-button-big-image-container'><img id='imgID_RibbonTabInsert_html_0' class='ribbon-button-big-image' src='custom.png'></img></div>";
            sCustomTabContent += "                  <div class='ribbon-button-big-label-container'>";
            sCustomTabContent += "                      <p class='ribbon-button-label'>Merge Code Group&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            sCustomTabContent += "                          <select id='ddlMergeCodeGroup'></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            sCustomTabContent += "                          Merge Code&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            sCustomTabContent += "                          <select id='ddlMergeCode'></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            sCustomTabContent += "                          <img id='insertField' src='images/Plus.png' alt='Add' height='20' width='20'></img>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            sCustomTabContent += "                          <img id='deleteField' src='images/minus.png' alt='Delete' height='20' width='20'></img>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            sCustomTabContent += "                      </p>";
            sCustomTabContent += "                  </div>";
            //sCustomTabContent += "              </div>";
            sCustomTabContent += "          </div>";
            sCustomTabContent += "      </div>";
            sCustomTabContent += "  </div>";

            //sCustomTabContent += "  <div class='ribbon-group-label-container'>";
            //sCustomTabContent += "      <p class='ribbon-group-label'>asdf</p>";
            //sCustomTabContent += "  </div>";
            sCustomTabContent += "</div>";
            sCustomTabContent += "</div>";

            // add the tab content to the tab content container 
            document.getElementById('txRibbonTabContentContainer').insertAdjacentHTML(
                'afterbegin', sCustomTabContent);
        }

        function activateCustomTab() {
            $('div.tab-content').css("display", "none");
            $('ul.tabs a').removeClass("selected");

            $("#ribbonTabCustom").css("display", "inline-block");
            $("#tabCustom").addClass("selected");
        }
    </script>    
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding style='pointer-events: all; to img tag attributes.  Click event is raised now.